# Injective function from rationals to any ordered field?

Tags: real-analysis

How could I define an injective function $f: \mathbb{Q}\mapsto \mathbb{K}$ with $\mathbb{K}$ an ordered field, such that
$$f(r+s)=f(r)+f(s)$$
$$f(rs)=f(r)f(s)$$
$$\text{if } r<s \Rightarrow f(r)<f(s)$$

I've tried proving that there exist a function $g: \mathbb{Z}\mapsto \mathbb{K}$ which satisfies the above three conditions for $\mathbb{Z}$, as it's esier by induction on the adition and substraction of 1 by the rules
$$g(1)=1_{\mathbb{K}}$$
$$g(n+1)=g(n)+1_{\mathbb{K}} \hspace{4mm}\text{for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$}$$
and then define $f$ with $r=\frac{m}{n}$ as $f\left(\frac{m}{n}\right)=\frac{g(m)}{g(n)}$, however don't know how to prove the conditions for $f$, as if I do

\begin{align*}
f\left(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{m}{n}\right)&=f\left(\frac{an+bm}{bn}\right)\\
&=\frac{g(an+bm)}{g(bn)}\\
&=\frac{g(a)g(n)+g(b)g(m)}{g(b)g(n)}
\end{align*}

I can't just separate the denominator on $\mathbb{K}$ as $\frac{g(a)g(n)}{g(b)g(n)}+\frac{g(b)g(m)}{g(b)g(n)}$ and simplify, or can I? If not, how could I prove the conditions?

Comment: "Separating the denominator" is perhaps a bad way to describe it.  It's just the distributive property, which holds for any ring/field, in particular any ordered field: $$\frac{x+y}{z} := (x+y)z^{-1} = xz^{-1} + yz^{-1} := \frac{x}{z} + \frac{y}{z}$$